# Can't view xml in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

I'm working on a java project that utilizes XML files in Eclipse; however, I can't get it to open the file in XML mode.  It merely shows it as a text file.  I have Eclipse Indigo (which I believe is the current version).  Any suggestions on how to get it to open correctly?

Note: If it makes any difference I have OS Lion and I can't view XML in Safari either.

Comment: Did you try right-click on file open as?

Comment: Yes, I've tried going to "Open with" however there is no option for open with XML editor/viewer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to help->eclipse marketplace then search for xml editor, install the Rinzo XML Editor restart eclipse and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Add the xml file to a project and right-click->open with->xml editor
However, it automatically opens in xml editor for me.
If you at any time want to see the source, at the bottom of the editor there will be a source  tab and a design tab

[How do I view xml in Eclipse with simple syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590119/how-do-i-view-xml-in-eclipse-with-simple-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Right-Click -> Open With..  ->XML Editor? If that option is not there, then some plugin is missing

Comment: That option is not there.  How do I get the plugin?

Comment: Look here, it looks like your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748350/unable-to-edit-xml-files-but-can-edit-java